# How to add multiple notifcaitons without being overridden

Tags: android, notifications

In my application I have to display notification form a background service when given condition reaches.

Example:

```
while(i<=50)
{

if(i%2==0)
{
notifyUser();
}
}
```

notifyUser() method `contains code for simple notification`

My question is how to get all the notifications when the condition reaches 
what i am getting is the last notification of the loop`How to achieve notifications witout being overridden just like facebook notification`Help me

Answer (score 1):

use different IDs for each notification.